# How to disable the "You cannot access this right now" modal pop-up dialog in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

#### Context

I have two email accounts added to my Outlook desktop client. One of them only is accessible when I am in a certain network, either directly plugged in or via VPN.

Now, when I am not in that particular network or VPN, this annoying dialog keeps popping up every couple minute; not like once an hour, but every darn few minutes!

[image]

The text says:

> You cannot access this right now
>
> Your sign-in was successful but does not meet the criteria to access
> this resource. For example, you might be signing in from a browser,
> app, or location that is restricted by your admin.

The *More details* links shows some account specific technical details like email address, "Triggered by conditional access", device plattform etc.

#### Problem

The problem is that this pop-up is modal and blocks Outlook until I click the *OK* button.

Also, it's sometimes hidden, so I only see the Outlook window which then looks frozen until I somehow get that pop-up to the front. The pop-up does not have a own entry in the Windows task bar, which means I have to click through all open Outlook windows until this pop-up becomes visible.

#### Workaround

One workaround would be to remove that account as long as I am not in that particular network so I can keep working with the other email account. But that is really tedious.

Another workaround would be to use Outlook Web Access in the browser instead of the desktop client, but that would be less convenient because I use a lot of keyboard shortcuts.

#### What I've tried

I've tried to disable *Send/Receive* but that didn't help. Even though *Send/Receive* is indeed disabled, that annoying pop-up keeps appearing.

- [How to Disable an Outlook Email Account But Not Delete It](https://account.lfchosting.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=181)

#### Question

Is there a way to prevent that modal pop-up from popping up every few minutes?

#### Version

- Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus Outlook version 1907

Comment: Do you have to use Outlook?

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser: Yes, I do. Sort of. I could use Outlook Web Access in the browser. But that would be less convenient. I've added that above in the "Workaround" section.

Comment: Why not use a different email program for the VPN based account?  It may not look it, but the core outlook functionality has not changed much in the past 10 years or so, so the best way to work with this might be to work around it.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser: Yes, if I don't get a better solution, I might go for what you are suggesting. I'll remove the VPN-based account and open it via Outlook Web Access when needed. However, I will lose the handy feature of being able to easily move / drag-and-drop emails between the accounts. But I can live without that feature.

Comment: Why not set up an alias or mail forwarding or something like that?

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser: Technically possible, yes, but legally I'm not allowed to set up mail forwarding from that particular company account to a non-company account. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can't click your way through this, this issue occurs due to unconditional access being enabled in a business. What does that mean ? It basically means that you can't use O365 or office applications outside the domain or network of your business. You can only use it within the domain on a PC that's part of that domain.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your problem, but it is worth mentioning that I had this problem pestering me occasionally for months.  The error SAYS that something have been restricted by an administrator, but that turned out to be **entirely** false.

What actually happened to me was that a Microsoft credential file was corrupted.  The solution was to go to the Credential Manager, and delete all the existing credentials.   Then I had to log in again, but the new credential files were not corrupted, and this solved the problem.  I was granted access.  No administrator changed any rights.

Anyone who hits this question and does not have another solution should at least try this approach to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is over a year old, but I was getting the same issue.  Once I disconnected from my work VPN, I would get that *(%#&#! pop-up every few minutes.

I disabled it by going to the systray and right-clicking on the Teams icon > Settings.
Unselected the "On close, keep the application running" checkbox.
Closed settings, then opened the systray again, right-clicked Teams > Quit.
No more pop-up!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I finally figured out the Excel spreadsheet prompting me to have to sign in to my Microsoft account had a link to a very old file on another network that didn't exist anymore .  Once I broke the link the prompt to login to Microsoft leading to the message stopped.